# numpy row order in the representation of vector funcions

Tags: numpy

Suppose I need to represent a vector-valued signal. Let's say the coordinate of a point rotating in the plane:

```
t = 0.05 * np.arange(100)
x = np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(t)
```

Now I have defined the position in this manner:

```
p = np.array([x,y])
```

so that time is the last axis of my multi-vector. This is fine in many respects (actually I deal with 3D-vectors and 3x3 matrices).

However in many situations I feel that having time on the first axis would be better. For example, if I have a constant positition

```
p0 = np.array([1.0,1.0])
```

it would be nice to write (p - p0) for the difference... which I cannot express so cleanly if time is the last axis!

I know that it is only a matter of taste, but is there in the numerical community a preferred or conventional choice in this situation?

I thought that the Matrix-Vector product would be a nice test to understand if the library is designed with a preference in one of the two choices. But I found no way to express such an operation in a simple way in neither case... (I have tried both dot product and matrix_vector_product, but at the end I find myself using np.einsum):

```
>>> M.shape
(2, 2, 100)
>>> v.shape
(2, 100)
>>> np.einsum('ij...,j...', M, v)
```

Comment: Take a look at [PEP 465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), going forward, if `a` has shape `(100, 2, 3)` and `b` `(100, 3, 4)`, you will be able to do `a @ b` to compute a matrix of shape `(100, 2, 4)` with 100 matrix multiplications. So I guess that is what things seem to be leaning towards.

Comment: Is a definitive answer possible to your question (which you claim is 'only a matter of taste')? I could make an argument for time on the first axis (as you will find in most data files as you can perhaps more easily append a row to a file rather than a column), but would that answer your question? Are you familiar with the concept of broadcasting in numpy? In your example p-p0 would work when written as p-p0[:,None]. Your matrix multiplication is also possible when taking the broadcasting rules into account.

Comment: Similar question: Order of indexes in a Numpy multidimensional array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606209/order-of-indexes-in-a-numpy-multidimensional-array/27611264#comment43744003_27611264